# Editable formulas relating variables in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, formula

I have a project where am designing a MySQL + PHP employee evaluation system. It should provide "admin" control where the admin can change the evaluation questions, the formula to calculate final employee rating and the weight of each question.

So I need a way to save and execute a formula in MySQL dynamically that uses elements in the database. For example, if the evaluation formula is a simple average:

```
(Rating1 + Rating2 + Rating3) / 3
```

where "Rating" is a dynamic number taken from another table/row.

The Admin should be able to view this formula and change it if needed to anything for example:

```
(Rating1 * 0.5 + Rating2 * 0.25 + Rating3 * 0.25) /3
```

So using again whatever elements available and creating an equation and saving it again in a usable form in the database.

how can this be done?

Comment: is easy you can use  dinamic sql .. just  store the part of code you need  in a string and a build a proper sql command  joining the string  .

Comment: I don't need any part of code all of the equation is dynamic it can change completely

Comment: your comment is not clear to me..  ..anyway sql code is interpreted dinamically  .. so you can store in a string ( a valid) code you prefer  just remember of use a valid sql sintax and proper columns  name

Comment: I don't want a normal equation inserted by a user. I want to be able to insert an equation that involved elements from the DB where the user doesn't know the right names of these elements. And this can completely change over time using a whole different set of elements and calculations. Eventually this equation will be used to generate reports and data from different elements in the DB.

Comment: but the admin  .. know the equation that must be inserted and know the name of the element in BD  ?  .. or all these info come  frome a a magic land?? .. if the admin know equationb and db  the comment above contain valid suggestion ..

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting the context, then what you need is this formula
(Rating1*X + Rating2*Y + Rating3*Z)/3

### EXPLANATION:

By default X, Y and Z equates to 1.
If you want to overwrite the values of X, Y and Z then supply it the values using input tags using ajax.

Comment: OK. "Rating" though refers to a row in another table. And it might change completely. Retrieving it as a text will not make it usable to generate results right?

Comment: Then why retrieve it as text? Retrieve it as an integer.

Comment: its an equation that I need to edit. sometimes I will use it in reports sometimes I will edit it